# Do we need to acquire distributed lock when we generate sequence id using redisson RAtomicLong?

Tags: redisson, sequence-generators

Do we need to acquire distributed lock when we generate sequence id using redisson RAtomicLong?
We are using redis cluster setup and to avoid same id being generated twice in case of failover of a clsuter node should we acquire lock?